# New to eclipse and need help changing text

Tags: c, eclipse, ide

I put dark mode on but the text in preferences is dark so I cannot see anything at all.

I'm on a Mac

[You will not see anything because of the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9pO7.png)

Comment: Did you restart Eclipse after changing the setting to Dark? The text should switch to being white. It works fine here with Eclipse 2020-12 and macOS 11.2

Comment: Yeah I did, multiple times as a matter of fact. Since my Mac was in dark mode, eclipse was already in dark mode.